# How to integrate activity indicator throughout the project

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, activity-indicator

I need to show `ActivityIndicator` in almost all pages from `ViewModels` in my application

```
<ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
   IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
   Color="Black"
   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
```

So is there any **easy way** to do it or need to have **above code** in all pages?

Answer (score 0):

Create **CustomView** for ActivityIndicator and create binding properties of ActivityIndicator in **BaseViewModel** .Now you can append this custom view in each page and handle binding properties through respective **ViewModel** which is inherited by **BaseViewModel**.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an extended method, in which you can add an `ActivityIndicator`. Now, in whichever page you need to show it, simply call this method in that Page's Constructor.

```
public static class ActivityIndicatorControl
{
    public static void AddActivityIndicatorControl(this ContentPage page)
    {
        var activityIndicator = new ActivityIndicator
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        };

        activityIndicator.SetBinding(VisualElement.IsVisibleProperty, "IsBusy");
        activityIndicator.SetBinding(ActivityIndicator.IsRunningProperty, "IsBusy");

        var grid = new Grid();
        grid.Children.Add(page.Content);
        grid.Children.Add(activityIndicator);
        page.Content = grid;
    }
}
```

Page's Backend:

```
public partial class MySamplePage : ContentPage
{
    public MySamplePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AddActivityIndicatorControl();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to your BaseViewModel with IsBusy Property, so whenever you make IsBusy=True it will show the loading indicator and hide it when you make IsBusy=false for the respective viewmodel, no need to add any xaml code anywhere Just add Acr.Dilogues nuget package like [here](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs).

For that I am using Acr.UserDilogues, sample code as follows,

```
    private bool _isBusy;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get
        {
            return _isBusy;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ref _isBusy, value);
            //TODO Comment below code for Custom Loading Indicator
            if (_isBusy)
            {
                UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading();
            }
            else
            {
                UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
            }
        }
    }
```